# Spring with JPA not persisting objects

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have read many tutorials to config spring with JPA. I am using a local MySQL database and i have this context:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DataSource Setup -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="vitornobrega" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.vitornobrega.myapp.entities" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
</beans>
```

I have a test on JUnit to test my DAO and works nice but when i try to persist an entity with this config, i never the in hibernate log the insert command but in test case i see it. If i try to make a entitymanager.flush i get an exception because any transaction is running.

What i should change to can make persist on my local database with this entities?
thanks

Comment: could you share please your stacktrace to see what the error is? So we can analyze it better and help you.

Answer (score 1):

> If i try to make a entitymanager.flush i get an exception because any transaction is running.

If I'm reading that right, the problem is you're trying to save something without starting a transaction. Transactions are required when changing persistent state.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to persist in database it is mandatory to be within a transaction. So the better you can solve it is to annotate @Transactional ... e.g. on the method

This also make me crazy for couple of hours some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

are you using annotations in your classes? if so please make sure you 
    `<context:component-scan base-package="com.vitornobrega.myapp">` because arpart from the jpa configurations i can see where you are injecting your dependencies.